# I can't add sentry to php slim

Tags: php, error-handling, sentry, slim-3

I need to add php sentry error handler to my slim 3 project.
how can I do so ?
where should put sentry integration code?
what I'm doing now is :

```
// monolog
$container['logger'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['logger'];
    $logger = new Monolog\Logger($settings['name']);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor());
    $logger->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler($settings['path'], $settings['level']));

    $client = new Raven_Client(
        'http://key@ip:9000/2'
    );

    $handler = new Monolog\Handler\RavenHandler($client);
    $handler->setFormatter(new Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter("%message% %context% %extra%\n"));

    $logger->pushHandler($handler);

    return $logger;
};
```

but I'm not getting all errors in my sentry dashboard.
for example accessing undefined array indexes.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a custom error handler to catch exceptions. This way i can use the default slim error handler and Sentry error reporting at the same time.

This is my code:

```
// initalize sentry
Sentry\init(['dsn' => 'your_dsn' ]);

// Run app
$app = (new App())->get();

// register custom error handler
$c = $app->getContainer();
$c['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function ($request, $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        // send error to sentry
        Sentry\captureException($exception);

        // invoke default error handler
        $handler = new Slim\Handlers\Error();
        return $handler->__invoke($request, $response, $exception);
    };
};

$app->run();
```

Not sure if this is the "recommended" way, but it works.

Comment: I think it's a valid way. But don't forget to use the *displayErrorDetails* like `new Slim\Handlers\Error($c['settings']['displayErrorDetails'])`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to just do the following (I did not test this or have ever used Slim but looking at the Slim docs this is *a* way to do it):

In your `index.php` (which should be the app entrypoint) just after `require '../../vendor/autoload.php';` (the composer autoload).

Add the Raven initialization code:

```
$sentry = new Raven_Client('http://key@ip:9000/2');
$sentry->install();
```

This will configure the SDK to handle (and send) all errors, no need for the Monolog handler anymore.

If you want to integration it in a `ErrorHandler` class you created looking at [this skeleton project](https://github.com/rakshazi/slim-skeleton) might give you some ideas.